# Colorbox not resizing to the correct height

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, imagesloaded

I am trying to load inline HTML into a colorbox which is working fine, except the colorbox is not adjusting to the correct height.

The inline HTML content is very long in height (approx 15,000 pixels), but only 900 pixels are being loaded.

So I started using the colorbox.resize() function to fix the problem e.g:

```
        $('.inline-html').colorbox({ 
            onComplete : function() { 
               $(this).colorbox.resize(); 
            }    
        });
```

But the resize function only works up to about 11,000 pixels (not the required 15,000 pixels). However, If I refresh the page twice, it loads the full 15,000 pixels.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Thanks

Comment: try using a fixed size to your colorbox and give it this css attribute: `overflow:scroll' .

Comment: I am using the browsers scrollbar (as opposed to the colorbox scrollbar), thus setting scrolling: false; and $(this).colorbox.resize(); -- If I used the colorbox scrollbar, then the correct height works. But my client wants to use the browsers scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

1. I've seen this happen when there are images in the colorbox which are not loaded when onComplete fires, so colorbox resizes to the height of the content minus the images. Then the images load and a scrollbar is created. If you can set a height for unloaded images, the problem may disappear because colorbox will know what size it is immediately. Ex:

   ```
   <p>Really long content.</p>
   <p>Really long content.</p>
   <img src="image.jpg" height="300">
   <p>Really long content.</p>
   ```

---

2. If you know the colorbox will be 15,000 pixels, can you set the colorbox to be that tall in css? Or run `$.colorbox.resize({height:"15,000"})`?

---

3. Probably the worst option, you could resize it after a timeout to give the images time to load. This is unreliable because the images will load at different times for different people, but if the problem is the images, this may help you troubleshoot.

   ```
   window.setTimeout($.colorbox.resize(), 500);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 1) I've added the image heights but still experiencing the same problem. Also, the majority of the contents are images (90% images, 10% text). 2) I have about 20+ colorbox's on the same page which are dynamically loaded - so unfortunately they are all different heights. 3) ... hmm yeah doesn't seem great, I am using the ImagesLoaded Jquery library though, might be able integrate this somewhere.